# How can i select particular items of array with Bash

Tags: bash

I have an array which i want to create a new array based on that, which contains just my particular selected items by index number.

for example i want to have an array which contains just `two` and `five` or with index number `[2,4]`

do you have an idea how to do it with bash script. i am new in bash
 thanks

```
array1=( one two three four five )
echo ${array1[@]}
```

result

```
array2 = (two five)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would need a loop:

```
indices=(1 3)
for i in "${indices[@]}"; do  # or for i in 1 3, if you want to hard-code the indices
  array2+=("${array[i]}")
done
```

Answer (score 2):

As far as I'm aware, the only way that you can do this is by making a new array, picking each element one by one:

```
array2=( "${array1[1]}" "${array1[4}}" ) # two five
```

If on the other hand you wanted a slice (consecutive indices), you could use the built-in syntax:

```
array2=( "${array1[@]:1:3}" ) # two three four
```